# C++ return by reference stack allocation details

Tags: c++

can someone walk through exactly what happens with the memory in this operator overload function? I am confused on how exactly the object created inside the operator function gets deallocated in the main.

```
Object& operator+(const Object& other) {
  Object o(*this); //create instance of o that deep copies first argument
  ...
  //copy contents of other and add onto o
  return o;
}
int main() {
  Object b;
  Object c;
  Object a = b + c;
}
```

Edit: to be more specific, isn't it bad practice to create a local object in a function and then return it by reference? Wouldn't that cause a memory leak?

Edit 2: I am referencing my textbook *Data abstraction & problem solving with c++ carrano* which suggests an operator + overload for LinkedLists in this format: `LinkedList<ItemType>& operator+(const LinkedList<ItemType>& rightHandSide) const;`. They implemented the method in the way I described.

Edit 2.5: the full method pseudocode given by the book:

```
LinkedList<ItemType>& operator+(const LinkedList<ItemType>& rightHandSide) const {
  concatList = a new, empty instance of LinkedList
  concatList.itemCount = itemCount + rightHandSide.itemCount
  leftChain = a copy of the chain of nodes in this list
  rightChain = a copy of the chain of nodes in the list rightHandSide
  concatList.headPtr = leftChain.headPtr
  return concatList
}
```

Edit 3: Asked my professor about this. Will get to the bottom of this by tomorrow.

Edit 4: The book is wrong.

Comment: It's undefined behavior, plain and simple. Don't return references to objects with automatic storage duration.

Comment: It must return `*this` instead of `o`. This code causes undefined behaviour and can crash any time. If you'll try to add some lines like `int i = 1;` after the plus, you can catch it.

Comment: The lifetime of `o` is ended at the end of `operator+()` function. Use it in main is undefined behavior

Comment: Anyway, `operator+` should return a value instead of a reference

Comment: Yes, it's terrible practice. Where did you find this? Was it in any real code, or did you just make it up without understanding it? What is the purpose of the question?

Comment: @Danh @underscore_d I am referencing my textbook _Data abstraction & problem solving with c++ carrano_ which suggests an operator + overload for LinkedLists in this format: `LinkedList<ItemType>& operator+(const LinkedList<ItemType>& rightHandSide) const;`. They implemented the method in the way I described. Why do you think the textbook used return by reference if it's dangerous?

Comment: Surely the textbook doesn't return a reference to a local scope object?

Comment: @PeterStock Wow, I hope not. Even if not, since when is `operator+` meant to return a reference? I'm pretty sure that's contrary to standard operators for built-in types and hence extremely poor form.

Comment: @EdwardHu Please show the actual code you're referring to, not some paraphrased version of it. If this book does what you're saying, all extant copies must be pulped immediately.

Comment: To address your *Edit 2* : Get a better textbook. If it can't get something as basic as this right, it shouldn't be used as a reference.

Comment: @EdwardHu, this is not how the textbook **implements** `operator+`, there is no return type specified. The book for all we know could be correct and return by value, while it is you who misunderstood.

Comment: @StoryTeller The book has declared the pseudocode function as `LinkedList<ItemType>&
operator+(const LinkedList<ItemType>& rightHandSide) const;`.

Comment: @EdwardHu, than I stand by what I previously said. Get a new book ASAP. If it's assigned to you by an instructor, take everything said there with a grain of salt. The fact you asked about this, shows you have a decent understanding of the problems involved.

Comment: @EdwardHu I agree; it's great that you're expressing scepticism about this and going to ask your prof. Thanks for making us aware of the book and the various highly questionable things it's indicating.

Comment: @EdwardHu If that book tells you the `operator+()` return a reference, throw it out, find a new book. Anyway, can you post your professor's answer to this thread?

Comment: @EdwardHu @underscore_d Updated tip: `operator+=(...)` should return a reference to self, `operator+(...)` should return a value

Comment: @danh will report back as soon as professor replies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Returning a reference to a local object

As everyone else correctly states, returning a reference to a local object results in undefined behaviour. You will end up with a handle to a destroyed function-scope object.

### Returning references in arithmetic operators

If you think about it, `a+b` should give you a result, but it shouldn't change `a` nor `b`. C++ however leaves it up to you to define how operators work on your own types so it's possible to implement the behaviour you need. This is why the `operator+` usually has to create a new object and can't return a reference.

Compound assignments (`+=`, `-=`, etc) on the other hand do change the object itself so `a += b` is changing `a`. This is why it's usually being implemented by returning a reference (not to a local object, but to the instance itself):

```
Object& Object::operator+=(const Object& rhs)
{
    // do internal arithmetics to add 'rhs' to this instance
    return *this; // here we return the reference, but this isn't a local object!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is simply **undefined behavior**.

In terms of what happens to memory, the memory will not be reserved to the object after the function returns (because the object is now out of scope).

So it can contain ANYTHING, *including the same object by way of coincidence*.

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't cause a memory leak, but `o` gets destroyed when it goes out of scope, when the function returns. So the reference the caller has is junk. It *might appear* to work fine for a short time until the memory is overwritten later.